# Append/Add Child Div (jQuery) for Messaging System

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm having difficulty trying to append/add a child div to the parent div, and thought someone out here may know the best way for me to go about this.  I have attached my code (without PHP right now, just hard coding text and stuff).  But here is what I am trying to do:

- When a message is posted, you hit the "Reply Button" and a new div will appear underneath containing the reply form.

Right now, here are the issues I know about and can't get around:

- The DIV is a class, so when I use jQuery to try to target the DIV it targets everything since it's no unique.
- The Reply Button is also a class, so it's not unique.

Here is a video of it in action: http://tinypic.com/r/2luxwnr/7

```
<body>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="message-viewer">
            <div class="roar">
                <div class="roaractionpanel">
                    <div id="msg-business2"></div>
                    <div class="roartime"><p class="roartime-text">3:26PM</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="roarcontent">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-reply"></button>
                    <h5>Test Post</h5><br>
                    <h6>Lord Varlin</h6><br>
                    <h2>Test post... let's see.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="newreply">
                <div class="newreplycontent">
                    <h1>This is where the fields for a new reply will go.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="roar">
                <div class="roaractionpanel">
                    <div id="msg-business2"></div>
                    <div class="roartime"><p class="roartime-text">3:26PM</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="roarcontent">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-reply"></button>
                    <h5>Testing another</h5><br>
                    <h6>Lord Varlin</h6><br>
                    <h2>Hmm dee dumm...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="roarreply">
                 <div class="roarreply-marker">
                    <p class="roarreplytime-text">June 26th @ 4:42AM</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="roarreplycontent">
                    <h9>Testing a reply.  Hmmmm.</h9><br>
                    <h8>Lord Varlin</h8>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="newreply">
                <div class="newreplycontent">
                    <h1>This is where the fields for a new reply will go.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="roar">
                <div class="roaractionpanel">
                    <div id="msg-business2"></div>
                    <div class="roartime"><p class="roartime-    text">3:26PM</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="roarcontent">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-reply"></button>
                    <h5>Testing another</h5><br>
                    <h6>Lord Varlin</h6><br>
                    <h2>jQuery, work with me please.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="roarreply">
                 <div class="roarreply-marker">
                    <p class="roarreplytime-text">June 26th @ 4:42AM</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="roarreplycontent">
                    <h9>Testing a reply.  Hmmmm.</h9><br>
                    <h8>Lord Varlin</h8>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="roarreply">
                 <div class="roarreply-marker">
                    <p class="roarreplytime-text">June 26th @ 4:42AM</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="roarreplycontent">
                    <h9>Testing a reply.  Hmmmm.</h9><br>
                    <h8>Lord Varlin</h8>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="newreply">
                <div class="newreplycontent">
                    <h1>This is where the fields for a new reply will go.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".btn-reply").click(function() {

    $(".newreply").toggleClass("show");
    return false;

 });
```

So, I see the flaws, but I just can't wrap my head around how to pull this off!  Any guidance would be awesome!  :)

Comment: Assuming I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you want the .btn-reply to only show the form for its roarcontent parent, and no other divs, correct?

Comment: Hi, you should make it easier to target the .newreply div. You can do it as well now using .parent() and .siblings() or .next() (etc) but it's unreliable if you change the markup. Either set classes or IDs or group them by children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.btn-reply').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.roar').siblings('.newreply').toggleClass('show');
    return false;
});
```

However, I agree with `Francisc` that a better approach would be to modify the `HTML` and assign a unique `id` to each message set. That way you can grab the `.newreply` to show based on a shared unique `id` which would be agnostic regarding the positioning of the `HTML` layout.

E.g.

```
<div class="roar" rel="msg0">...</div>
...
<button class="btn-reply" rel="msg0"></button>
...
<div class="newreply" rel="msg0">...</div>
...
```

Then your jQuery becomes:

```
$('.btn-reply').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var selector = '.newreply[rel=' + id + ']';
    $(selector).toggleClass('show');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Only works if `.newreply` is child of `.btn-reply`.

I am not sure I understood right, but try this:

```
$(".btn-reply").click(function() {

    $(".newreply",this).toggleClass("show");
    return false;

 });
```

Note the `this` keyword after `".newreply"`.

Another way is to use `.find()`, like `$(this).find('.newreply').toggleClass("show");`.

Comment: @Fran I don't think those will work, newreply divs aren't descendants of btnreply divs, you need to travel up the dom, not down.

Comment: You have the button from $(this). You can go up using .parents([selector]) assuming the button inside the container you want, See: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: jacob is right, but this is not reliable in my oppinion. If you change the markup it will stop working. Read my comment to the question.

Comment: @Francisc No matter what you do, if you change your markup you are going to have to update you javascript. I think my answer is probably the best you are going to get to fit the question's requirements. Using $('a-button).parent('.div-i-want') will select the div better than $('#div') as it will work for all subsequent buttons. You could use the live() event as well: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should append a reply div after the parent 'roar' div that the clicked button is in:

```
$('.btn-reply').click(function () {
    var replyHtml = '..build inner html string for the reply here..'
    $('<div />' {
        className: 'newreply'
    }).html(replyHtml).insertAfter($(this).parents('.roar'));
});
```

You will need to do any set up of the newreply div in the javascript. E.g. adding click events